# .fbx model from Blender is black and transparent in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, fbx

I've made a model in Blender and only one object of it in Unity is black and transparent[picture of the model in Blender and Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tadVN.png)

The material is the same as in the part on the right of the images.[materials properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7EYZ.png)

0,

Answer (score 0):

I sounds and looks a bit like a problem with the mesh's normals pointing in the wrong direction at some points.

In blender, you can check, and modify, the normals of a mesh. See for example these links:

https://www.katsbits.com/codex/show-normals/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqsgrg_SVME

Comment: So i tried fliping the normals and it helpt with the transparency but didn't help with black